# Find the number of unique changes in a file, with gitpython

Tags: python, git, git-diff, gitpython

I want to determine how much a file has changed, since some date. What I have so far:

```
def find_changes(repo:git.Repo, file_to_check:str, since=None):
''' finds all commits in which the file with ending :param file_to_check was changed.
    :param since: all commits since for ex. '1970-01-01' '''
    commits_for_file = []
    file_listings = {}
    for i, comm in enumerate(repo.iter_commits("--all", since=since)):
        fs  = comm.stats.files
        fs = {f: val for f, val in fs.items() if (f.endswith(file_to_check))}  
        if len(fs) > 0:
            file_listings[i] = fs
            commits_for_file.append(comm)
    changes_this_file = [[val["lines"]  for f, val in c.stats.files.items()
                                if (f.endswith(file_to_check))]
                            for c in commits_for_file]
    total_changed = sum([ch for changes in changes_this_file for ch in changes])
    return total_changed, commits_for_file
```

The problem with this is that gitpython seems to return more commits than, for example, `gitk [filepath]` shows. In one example, gitk showed two commits (across the whole file history), while gitpython showed me six. None of the dates of those six fit to one of the two gitk commits.

In the commits found by gitpython, file changes seem to be duplicated (the number of lines added/deleted is the same for most of those commits, indicating that they all correspond to one single file change.) Many of the commits are merges of pull requests - maybe those are "duplicates" of the original commits with changes?

**My question:** In Python, how can I get the total number of lines changed across commits since date X, or alternatively, how can I get the number of lines that are different between two commits? This can be using [GitPython](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) or any other tool. I would prefer not having to parse the text output from a "git diff" run in a subprocess.

**Secondary question:** Why are the commits shown via gitk and GitPython so different, including the dates? There seems to be a fundamental difference in what those two utilities consider a commit.

Comment: With the git command: diff --stat <sha1> <sha2> you find the files and the amount of changes between two commits (which is I think what you want). However this is not implemented in gitpython. GitDiff is, so although you would no prefer having to parse that, you can make a function that does that for the specific file changed as al the information is on the string returned. On the other hand I don't know gitk, but according to my understanding gitpython gives you the correct commits where the file in question is involved, this is, the commits where the file was changed.

Comment: I ended up parsing the output from `[Gitpython-repo].git.diff(former_commit.tree, file_path, numstat=True)`. With numstat=True the format is really very simple to parse. Still using GitPython to find the old commit at a specific date.

Comment: for next time, check this library: https://github.com/ishepard/pydriller, it's an abstraction of GitPython and it helps in these things